# What is the STM32F103 USART oversampling value?

Tags: stm32, uart, datasheet, oversampling

There is the **stm32f10x_usart.c** file in the STM32F10x SPL. This file file has next strings

```
#define CR1_OVER8_Set   ((u16)0x8000)  /* USART OVER8 mode Enable Mask */
#define CR1_OVER8_Reset ((u16)0x7FFF)  /* USART OVER8 mode Disable Mask */
```

But the description of the USART_CR1 in the RM0008 Reference manual for STM32F10x says that the bit 15 is reserved. The search on the RM0008 manual with the "oversampling" word gives only two matches and there is no data that point to oversampling value (8 or 16 times).

So, what is the STM32F103 USART oversampling value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the reference manual [RM0008](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0008-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), Figure 284, each bit is sampled 16 times.

[image]

Also, the baud rate calculation is specified as follows:

[image]

This [STM320 USART lecture](https://fastbitlab.com/stm32-usart-lecture-8-usart-baud-rate-calculation-part-2/) breaks down this formula as,
[image],
which would match the oversampling rate of 16.

Answer (score 0):

This " oversampling value" (8 or 16 times) has been around for 50 years to pseudo#sync the 1st start bit edge to the Rx data latch.

In order to synchronize the asynchronous data a 16x clock counts 8 cycles from the leading edge of the start bit to centre sample the data and can tolerate up to a 10% f difference after 10 bits with perfect sync so sync error of 1/16th of a bit allows slightly less f error.

Since clocks are now crystal controlled, the f error is much  less and the margin is used for bit shift noise. In some cases Intersymbol interference (ISI) and asymmetry contribute to bit shift error at the RS232 input Rx threshold the same as TTL or 1.3V with a bipolar Tx signal.

At the max bit rates this clock is limited to 8x due to limitations.

Comment: It is not an answer to the question "what is the STM32F103 USART oversampling value?"

Comment: @Arseniy  Sorry you don't understand the limitations of 16x max baud rate cannot be achieved from the crystal so 8x is used. Does that 'splain it better ?  I answered your question with why. not how to address the register....  The value is always 16 unless it is the max baud rate. period.

Comment: Please use the voting system

Comment: what did you  mean to say?